# Django query to get a unique set based on a particular column's value

Tags: django, unique, django-queryset

Hope this makes sense...

Is there a simple way to return a set of values from a table based on a single column's values being distinctly unique? What I'm hoping for is something like:

```
SegCode.query.filter(ref.unique()).only('ref')
```

That's not real code, but I was hoping there was some simple function out there that will accomplish this...

---

E.g. Table might look like:

```
1 | abc | 123 | AAA  
2 | def | 456 | AAA  
3 | ghi | 789 | BBB  
4 | jkl | 012 | CCC  
5 | mno | 345 | CCC  
6 | pqr | 678 | CCC  
7 | stu | 901 | DDD  
8 | vwx | 234 | DDD
```

So, I'd like a set that comes back with: `[AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SegCode.objects.values_list('ref', flat=True).distinct()
```

I think this is what you're after, your question isn't really that clear

Comment: Haven't tried your code yet, but I just updated with some more info, hopefully clarifying what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok then, according to your edit, my code is exactly what you want

Comment: That only works if my SegCode class is a Django model, correct? What if my class was an Elixir Entity, meaning I had to use Querysets to do the query? I ask because I'm getting an error: type object 'SegCode' has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: If SegCode is an Elixir Entity, then the whole thing goes out the window. Elixir has nothing to do with django querysets. You'd have to create a separate question to address how to do it.

Comment: Thansk for your answer but can you tell me by what name I can access the values returned in this list in y template?

Comment: Dude! Thanks so much! I've been searching for hours on how to do this and only your sollution works.